# Get request not found, attempt to set ?value parameters inside a url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, insomnia

I did this get, with the intention of returning the amount of clients that the application needed, but insomnia only returns that it didn't find the route:

```
server.get('/consultclients?amount=1', (req,res) =>{
let amount = req.params.amount;

return res.json({amount})
})
```

Request insomnia: localhost:3003/consultclients?amount=10

I tried with a method that I used to search for an id, but I don't think it's the right method to use, even though it works:

```
server.get('/consultclients/:amount', (req,res) =>{
let amount = req.params.amount;

return res.json({amount})
})
```

Request insomnia: localhost:3003/consultclients/10

Answer (score 2):

Try the base path `.get('/consultclients', …)`, and then see if `req.query.amount` (`req.query` instead of `req.params`) is populated when you make your request.

Comment: It looks like it was the req.query I really needed, and this route correction worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the search params. You can find them in the `req.query` in the request object instead of the `req.params`

This code example should work for you:

```
server.get('/consultclients', (req,res) =>{
  let amount = req.query.amount;

  return res.json({amount})
})
```

Comment: It looks like it was the req.query I really needed, and this route correction worked, thanks!